# pdo - How INSERT table value in Select and additionally string

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

He needs to insert a table of values from a select query and additionally string

```
    $query=("INSERT INTO table1 (a,b,c,d) VALUES ('a',SELECT b,c,d FROM  table WHERE x=1)");
```

Comment: who's he? please ask question properly http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you as *him* to try the following:

```
INSERT INTO table1 (a,b,c,d) VALUES (SELECT 'a',b,c,d FROM  table WHERE x=1)
```